# Is it possible to create a canonical URL for pages with just a pageid in confluence?

Tags: confluence

I need to groups each space in the Piwik web analytics software. The cleanest way to do it would be if all URL´s had the spacekey in it, to allow each space-owner to easily get a complete view of their space and retain all functionality like browsing the site with an analytics overlay.

Some URL´s are canonical, however some just have an URL like `/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=199921170`

Is there some way through the AJS API or other method to find force a working URL in the form: `/display/spacekey/title-of-page`

The most important part is to have the spacekey in the URL. If there´s no workaround I might just generate an invalid URL by inserting spacekey and let each space-owner fix their page-titles if they want working analytics :-)

We are running Confluence version 5.10.7

(There´s an unresolved open issue on https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-11285 concerning the broader issue of sometimes having ugly URLs in confluence)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an incorrect URL, you could use a custom variable to record the space key, e.g.

```
 _paq.push(['setCustomVariable','1','Space Key', AJS.params.spaceKey]);
```